# Image not showing in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, explorer, jpeg

This hi-res JPEG image won't show properly in FireFox and Chrome, but it does open in IE
http://www.irmatenbrinke.nl/images/stories/pers/MF76601.jpg

I can't find what's wrong. Some pointers would be very appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your web server is sending the wrong `content-type` header for some reason:

```
text/html
```

instead of

```
image/jpeg
```

you or your server admin will need to fix that. Maybe you have a .htaccess file somewhere with faulty content type instructions.

Comment: Thx, contacted server admin. They said it was probably the Joomfish component screwing things up. I don't want go hacking into an otherwise working Joomla component. 
I solved the problem by putting the images into ZIP files